# Android wrap_content width stops working for Textview

Tags: android

I've got a Textview that needs to vary it's width base on the content, so I set the layout_width to wrap_content. This works fine in portrait mode. I can update the text with setText and the width will follow.

Recently I wanted to add landscape support. I made some layout tweaks ,added a view-pager
so I can have some extra stuff on one half of the screen (not used in portrait).
The Textview is unchanged!

The app shows weights from a scale. So it will display the weight and then reset to 0 after a delay. After showing 3-4 measurements, the width will be locked to only allow one number to be displayed.
I've tried calling requestLayout on both the Textview and it's parent, as well as forceLayout, invalidate and everything else I can think of.
I've even tried calling measure to manually re-measure the width, then updating the layoutparam with the width from getMeasuredWidth, and still nothing.

If i get the activity to re-size by opening the keyboard, then it will start working again for a bit.

Here is part of the xml that holds the TextView:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llWeightParent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvScoopHead"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/weight_lables_negative_offset"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_weight_xxl"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoopUnit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="kg"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_weight_unit" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: can you post a video of this issue to understand better...

Comment: Here is a video of the issue. All weights are 4 digits long, but after a while only 1 gets displayed. I've tried adding a border to the Textview and that told me that is does not expand in size when this happens.
https://youtu.be/7gaQc_7Z4zo